# How do you search the text of changelist descriptions in Perforce?

Tags: perforce

On occasion, I find myself wanting to search the text of changelist descriptions in Perforce.  There doesn't appear to be a way to do this in P4V.  I can do it by redirecting the output of the changes command to a file...

```
p4 changes -l > p4changes.txt
```

...(the -l switch tells it to dump the full text of the changelist descriptions) and then searching the file, but this is rather cumbersome.  Has anyone found a better way?

Comment: The real solution would be for p4d to have a full text index on changelist descriptions (and the source files themselves....)  Kind of weird that has not made it into the product yet.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

When the submitted changelist pane has focus, a CTRL+F lets you do an arbitrary text search, which includes changelist descriptions.

The only limitation is that it searches just those changelists that have been fetched from the server, so you may need to up the number retrieved.  This is done via the "Number of changelists, jobs, branch mappings or labels to fetch at a time" setting which can be found by navigating to Edit->Preferences->Server Data.

Comment: Nice. Tried this out, and it jumps to select each matching changelist. Really handy.

Comment: I wish I could upvote again. I forgot and found this answer again today, but saw that I've already upvoted it.

Comment: As to me it's awful situation when p4v doesn't contain such useful search. Let's imaging situation when your CL is very olde (~more then two years old in highly developing application). You won't find it by this way.

Answer (score 24):

`p4 changes -L | grep -B 3 searchstring`

`-B 3` means show 3 lines before the matched string, should be enough to show the change id with 2 line comments but you can change it as necessary.

Answer (score 17):

I use [p4sql](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4report/01_install.html) and run a query on the "changes" database. Here's the [perforce database schema](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4report/aa_schema.html)

The query looks something like this (untested)

```
select change from changes where description like '%text%' and p4options = 'longdesc'
```

edit: added the p4options to return more than 31 characters in the description.

Comment: That didn't work.  For some reason, "like" behaves like "=".  Suppose the description is "foo bar".  like 'foo' fails, but like 'foo bar' succeeds.  More importantly, they don't make the entire text of the description available, only the first 30 characters.

Comment: @raven - The % characters are important to the SQL, and hould make teh query work. I also don't think you are correct in the description - you should be able to get to all of it. Can you post your query?

Comment: @Greg Whitfield: You're right, I wasn't using the % characters.  The queries are working, but not of much use.  I verified that it is only querying on, and displaying, the first 31 characters of the description.

Comment: @raven - updated the query to include p4options='longdesc'. that should return the full description.

Comment: p4options makes the query a bit slower though.

Comment: @jop: Great!  That did it.  I created a custom tool to make it easy to use and...  It doesn't freakin' work!  There's a bug in the custom tool argument parser.  I reported it to Perforce.  Hopefully they will address it and get an update out soon.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI: Perforce acknowledged the bug when I reported it last October, and have released updates to both P4V and P4Report, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a Powershell version of Paul's "grep" answer.  Again, it searches for the specified string within the change description and returns the 3 lines before it, to include the change id:

```
p4 changes -L | select-string "search string" -Context (3,0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Why redirect to a file when you can pipe the output through `less` and use `less`'s search?

```
p4 changes -l | less
```

And then press <kbd>/</kbd> to prompt for a search string.  Afterward, <kbd>n</kbd> will jump to the next match, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> will jump to the previous one.

An implementation of `less` for Windows is available as part of [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: This is probably the most user friendly option provided you already have less. I had it installed already with msys2, so it was easy to pull up.

Answer (score 1):

Using p4sql is really the only way to effectively do what you want.  I am not aware of any other way.  The benefit of course is that you can use the select statements to limit the range of changelist values (via date, user, etc).  Your method will work but will get cumbersome very quickly as you generate more changelists.  You can limit the scope of the changes command, but you won't get the flexibility of p4sql.

Answer (score 1):

Eddie on Games posted his Perforce Changelist Search 0.1 at http://www.eddiescholtz.com/blog/archives/130

But, I do like using my favorite text editor with the simple:
p4 changes -s submitted //prog/stuff/main/... >temp.txt

Comment: Version 0.2 is also. The code is hosted on google code: http://code.google.com/p/p4search/

Answer (score 0):

If you still love your command line, you can write a small perl script that:

- changes the record separator $/ to
  double newline "\n\n" so it filters
  the input into full records of the
  ztagged p4 output.
- scans
  the '/^... desc/..//' part with
  regular expressions from the args.

usage would be something like 'p4 -ztag changes -l | yourperlfilter.pl searchterm1 searchterm2'

if that worked ok, you could [integrate it into the p4win tools menu](http://markmail.org/message/ipcpb4ddbqhdmt43).