# How to search history in Perforce

Tags: perforce

It seems that there are no way to do that in P4V.

I can use 'Submitted Changelist'and but it's quite cumbersome and there I can only search by User & Workspace.

**I'd like to search the history by description.**

Is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: I asked the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134103/how-do-you-search-the-text-of-changelist-descriptions-in-perforce

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, P4Win has a "Find string" menu item that works on all the fields in the Submitted Changelists - very handy.

You can also do what you want from the command line, by piping the output of `p4 changes` through `grep` or something similar.